# PHP MySQL external database connection timed out

Tags: php, mysql, connection-timeout

I'm getting a connection timed out when I try to connect to an external (not on the same server as this code is on) database through the following code. I know the settings of the database is set up right, and the login info is good, 'cause I can login fine from my computer with HeidiSQL. If anyone can see a problem with this code, thanks.

```
function database_connect(){
$link = @mysql_connect("xx.xxx.xxx.xx:3306","root","pass"); 
$sql_error = mysql_error();

if (!$link) { 
    echo "Connection with the database couldn't be made.<br>";
    echo "$sql_error"; 
    exit;
}

if (!@mysql_select_db("databasename")) {
    echo "The database couldn't be selected.";
    exit;
}
return $link;
}
database_connect();
```

Comment: Can you `ping` the MySQL server from your PHP server? Or connect with the command-line `mysql` program?

Comment: Who is issuing the "connection timed out"? PHP? Your browser?

Comment: @BrendanLong Nope, connection timed out too.

Comment: general tip: don't allow remote root access to the DB server. that's just begging for a world of hurt. always use limited-rights accounts.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah, this is just a test.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly, can you quote it? If the connection is timing out on your server but not on your local PC, the problem might be with your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem known now.

My webhost does not allow connections to an external database.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding the IP address of where that script is hosted to "**Remote Database Access Hosts"**?
If you're on cPanel, you need to allow the IP address who can remotely access the datase(mysql).
If you're not, then this is just an idea of what to do.